# Protractor running code issue in visual studio code

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor, protractor-net

Could you please help/guide me  for running simple program on visual studio code because i created a new folder and created configuration.js  and spec.js file but i am getting below error while running code in protractor . i have updated version for npm(6.14),webdriver manager and protractor (7.0.0) but still not able to practice on eclipse and VS code .Could please help me to provide some good solution for making any program on visual studio code .

error :- [09:29:22] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[09:29:22] E/configParser - Error message: configuration file configuration.js did not export a config object
[09:29:22] E/configParser - Error: configuration file configuration.js did not export a config object
Thank you for hearing me in advance

[image]
Thank you

Amit G

Comment: Post your protractor config file please

Comment: // configuration.js
exports.config = {
     framework: 'jasmine',
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
     specs: ['spec.js']
   }

Comment: describe('Protractor  steps',function() {  


    it('Open Angular js website',function() {
    
    
    
    
     browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
    //write your protractor raw code
    
    
    
    })
    
     
    
    
    //Each it block will be called as a spec
    
    
    
   // it('close browswer', function() {
    
    
    
    // code to close browser
    //

//})
    
    
    
    })